# OAUTH 2 scope design

Tags: rest, api, oauth, scope, oauth-2.0

We have a support-center app which has some  rest api's for

Tickets ,Contacts , User Settings -> (Workflow,users,department,profiles and roles based authorisation) ,other-services 
integrated data api

We are trying to define Oauth scopes for these .The main questions we are finding difficulty with are :

- How fine grained should OAuth scopes be and what are the trade off's of fine grained vs coarse grained scopes.
- Can we have multiple scope associated to a single api endpoint ? 
  Eg 1: GET /workflow scope="automation,settings" .
  In this case those who has access to one of these scopes can access the api .

  Eg 2: GET /tickets ? include="contacts" scope="tickets,contacts" 
  Here ticket is the main data ,contact is optional.Not all api requests will ask for contact's info ,but if they do 
  they need to have contact access .In this case either the resource sever will have to reject the request or filter the data 
  based on scope.
- How to define scope for integrated data persisted on our side or fetched from other resource servers

  Eg : GET /contacts/{id}/associatedCrmContact.

  Contacts from our side are mapped to the same contacts in a crm app .To fetch this data we provide the above endpoint
- We already have an authorisation at app level .This is a profile,role based authorisation which can be reconfigured 
  by the support admin at any point .We also have really fine grained field level authorisations .The problems regaring 
  this are
  1.How should this dynamic user authorisation fit into new OAuth2 scopes .
  2.A person who doesnot have ticket add permission at app level shouldn't be able to provide it to a machine/app.
  3.Should we apply user level profile check irrespective of a machine or user
- How to define scopes where we have composite data contained inside the endpoint

  Eg1: GET tickets/{Id}/threads ,GET tickets/{Id}/comments , GET tickets/{Id}/conversation .The conversation endpoint contains 
  both thread and comments sorted by time

  Eg2:GET /feeds ,Feeds has tickets ,contacts,users ,department info